# Column aliasing with Subsonic 2.2

Tags: subsonic, subsonic2.2

Is there any way I can do

Select TableName.SomeColumn As SomeAlias FROM TableName

In Subsonic v2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
DAL.DB.Select(DAL.MyTable.MyColumn.QualifiedName + " AS SomeAlias")
    .From<DAL.MyTable>()
    ....
```